# iAd banner gives warning when pushed off screen by navController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, iad

I have a iAd that seems to be correctly displaying but when push a new view controller into the view i get a warning from the iAd that says it has been:

> WARNING A banner view (0x490fd0) has an ad but may be obscured. This message is only printed once per banner view.

But the ad still runs fine so should i pay attention to this?

I just tried adding

```
self.adBannerView = nil;
[adBannerView release];`
```

just before i push the viewController but i still get that error

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the banner view in ViewWillDisappear. It worked for me:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [adBannerView removeFromSuperview];
}
```